# Problema para visualizar fechas en componente Calendar primevue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primefaces, primevue

Estoy trabajando en un crud, cuyo frontend está escrito utilizando vuejs y la librería primevue. El problema está cuando intento crear un Calendario que me registre una fecha.

He seguido la documentación y hasta el momento todo parece estar en orden, pero no logro que el calendario me muestre ninguna fecha, sólo puedo ver el input vacio, y al darle click no salta el calendario como debería hacerlo.

**main.js**

```
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';

Vue.component('Calendar', Calendar)
```

**CrudApp.vue**

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
    <Calendar
          id="navigators"
          v-model="student.dob"
          :monthNavigator="true"
          :yearNavigator="true"
          yearRange="2000:2030"
    />
</div>

<script>
export default {
    created() {
        let today = new Date();
        let month = today.getMonth();
        let year = today.getFullYear();
        let prevMonth = (month === 0) ? 11 : month -1;
        let prevYear = (prevMonth === 11) ? year - 1 : year;
        let nextMonth = (month === 11) ? 0 : month + 1;
        let nextYear = (nextMonth === 0) ? year + 1 : year;
        this.minDate = new Date();
        this.minDate.setMonth(prevMonth);
        this.minDate.setFullYear(prevYear);
        this.maxDate = new Date();
        this.maxDate.setMonth(nextMonth);
        this.maxDate.setFullYear(nextYear);

        let invalidDate = new Date();
        invalidDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
        this.invalidDates = [today,invalidDate];
    },
    data() {
        return {
          student: {
            name: null,
            email: null,
            dob: null,
          },     
            
           minDate: null,
           maxDate: null,
           invalidDates: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.